# Proof of the existence of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am looking through my lecture notes, which follows Billingsley, regarding the proof of the existence of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$.

The theorem is: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{G}$ a $\sigma$-subfield of $\mathcal{F}$ and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a random variable that is integrable. Then there exists a function $E(X|\mathcal{G}):\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and integrable and $\int_{G} E(X|\mathcal{G}) dP=\int_{G} XdP$, for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

Now, the proof is broken up into 2 cases: 1. $X \ge 0$ and 2. $X$ integrable.

For case 1, we let $v(G)=\int_{G}XdP$ and, since $v(G)$ is finite and absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $P$, we use the Radon-Nikodym Theorem to get $v(G) = \int_{G} E(X|\mathcal{G}) dP$, for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

For case 2, we break let $X=X^{+}-X^{-}$, as usual, and apply case 1 to the non negative $X^{+}-X^{-}$ to get our results.

My question is, why are we breaking up the proof into 2 cases. What is so special about $X \ge 0$? We already know that $X$ is integrable. Why not jump to case 2?

Comment: We would like to see the sources where you read that.

Comment: It's in my lecture notes, which follows Billingsely, and it's in the proof for the existence of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$. The hypothesis already assume that $X$ is integrable, but the proof gives 2 cases: $X$ non negative and $X$ integrable. For the first case, my prof used the fact $X$ is non negative to deduce that the measure $v(A)=\int_{A} X dP$.

Comment: So, it appears that you paraphrased quite significantly the original texts. Did you read somewhere the exact sentence: "Since $X \ge 0$ then $\int_{\Omega}|X| dP< \infty$"?

Comment: Yes, I paraphrased that for brevity. I will edit this immediately.

Comment: When asking for correctness of a very specific statement, paraphrasing the statement is quite risky... if it's really too long, give a reference to the proof along with your question.

Comment: You are correct, and I apologize. I was on my iPad, and typing LaTeX codes on iPad keyboard is horrible. Lol.

Comment: And now we see that the odd statement in the first version of the question was not in the source at all. The answer to the, quite different, new version of the question is that Radon-Nykodym holds for nonnegative measures hence one needs to restrict oneself to nonnegative (integrable) random variables to apply it.

Comment: Thanks. I only thought the restriction was that the measure $P$ had to be $\sigma$-finite. I have never taken measure theory, so I don't know if $\sigma$-finite measure means that the measure is non negative.

Comment: *Look up the definitions*, again.

Comment: Sorry that I have brought this up again, but I just found an example as to why I asked this particular question. Textbook: A Probability Path, written by Resnick. Lemma 5.9.1, he has "furthermore suppose $X \ge 0$ ($X$ is integrable)" Usually when I see something in paragraphs, after a statement, I assume that what is in the paragraph is equivalent to the preceding question. I hope you can understand my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** *this answer addresses a previous version of the question, which since then has been completely modified. The answer to the new question is that the standard Radon-Nikodym theorem applies to measures (i.e., non-negative), not to signed or complex measures.*

This is wrong. All that can be said is that the integral exists in $[0,\infty]$, *not* that the integral is finite.

That is, $$0\leq \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \infty$$
but **not**
$$0\leq \mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$$

(also, why do the proofs you read put absolute values around $X$ if $X\geq 0$?)

E.g., you can take $X$ following the distribution with pdf $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)$. While non-negative a.s., $X$ does not have a finite expectation.

Comment: Thanks. I know you're right, I was just curious why a particular proof broke down 2 cases: $X$ being non negative and $X$ being integrable, when it was already given that $X$ is integrable.

Comment: Well, without the exact statement of the theorem and the corresponding proof you're referring to, it's hard to tell.